# Windows 8 store app development without touch screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've started doing Windows 8 Store app development for some projects at work, but I do not have a touch screen device of my own at home. If I write a personal app for submission to the store, I must use my own hardware since I can't use the work computers for personal projects. My concern is getting into a situation where I submit an app to the store, then have touch-screen users describing issues that I can't replicate on a non-touch-screen device.

Are there any functions or capabilities or interactions that behave differently in a Windows 8 store app when using touch vs. using only a mouse? Are there any scenarios I could encounter where I would be at a loss to reproduce or troubleshoot a user's problems if I do not have a touch screen?

Comment: as a tangent to your question (and dependent on location) reach out to your [Microsoft Developer Evangelists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb905078) as many are holding events and office hours to provide access to devices for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft have introduced events that are pointer agnostic meaning that they should function the same way regardless of whether you are using a touchscreen, a mouse or a pen. Those are the `MSPointer` events. [Here's some documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/20/touch-input-for-ie10-and-metro-style-apps.aspx). Using event handlers for these events mean that you should not be getting complaints from users about the touch friendliness of your application. However I still strongly suggest that you acquire a surface and test your application on it. Not just for the touch friendliness but also because of performance differences.

Comment: I would agree that the performance profile is the bigger differentiator here. Simulator will get most touch issues delt with, but nothing will mimic the perf.

Answer (score 5):

As Konstantin suggested, a tablet is strongly recommended.

The next best thing is to use the device simulator in Visual Studio. It will let you change screen sizes, and allows you to simulate basic touch gestures with the mouse. This MSDN link has more info: [Testing Windows 8 apps using Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/08/20/testing-windows-8-apps-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx)